# c# Json retrieve a specific node with his level

Tags: c#, json

I've created two c# classes and then deserialize the Json returned to work with it natively.

```cs
class structureTree
{
    public structureChildren[] children { get; set; }
}

class structureChildren
{
    public structureChildren[] children { get; set; }
    public string myentity { get; set; }
    public bool sonGuide { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public Int64 structureId { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}
```

The Data returned is like this

```json
[
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "children": [
              {
                "children": [],
                "myentity": "ENT2_A",
                "from": "2019-10-01",
                "structureId": 34353,
                "to": null
              },
              {
                "children": [
                  {
                    "children": [],
                    "myentity": "ENT3_A",
                    "from": "2019-10-01",
                    "structureId": 34349,
                    "to": null
                  },
                  {
                    "children": [],
                    "myentity": "ENT3_B",
                    "from": "2019-10-01",
                    "structureId": 34351,
                    "to": null
                  }
                ],
                "myentity": "ENT2_B",
                "from": "2019-10-01",
                "structureId": 34348,
                "to": null
              }
            ],
            "myentity": "ENT1_A",
            "from": "2019-10-01",
            "structureId": 34348,
            "to": null
          }
        ],
           "myentity": "ENT0_A",
            "from": "2019-10-01",
            "structureId": 34348,
            "to": null

      }
    ]
    }   
]
```

I need to get all "myentity" elements and if it's possible in which level resides.

If not possible obtain level, another way is get all "myentity" for each level.

Comment: The JSON is not complete / valid

Comment: "Which level" - how are you going to count a level? 1,2,3 a,b,c or something else. You have post json you want , otherwise it is hard to understand your problem.  Post header says return all children, but inside you want myentity. What do you really want?

Comment: JSON corrected. Sorry, but cut and past is terrible when you're in delay.

Comment: Title changed, you're right. I don't have a node that tells me the level, I just have a recursive structure for node called children.
I need to obtain something like this: [ENT0_A, 1] [ENT1_A, 2] [ENT2_A, 3] ...etc.

Comment: It is possible to restore the original question score (now -3).

Answer (score 1):

Probably there are much better and elegant ways of doing this. This is without thinking on it much:

```
void Main()
{
    var st = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<structureTree>>(myjson);
    List<Tuple<string,int>> entities = new List<System.Tuple<string, int>>();
    foreach (var stc in st)
    {
        foreach (var sc in stc.children)
        {
            GetMyEntity(entities, sc, 0);
        }
    }
    foreach (var e in entities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Item1}, {e.Item2}");
    }
}
void GetMyEntity(List<Tuple<string,int>> entities, structureChildren c, int level)
{
    entities.Add(Tuple.Create(c.myentity,level));
    level++;
    foreach (var sc in c.children)
    {
        GetMyEntity(entities, sc, level);
    }
}
class structureTree
{
    public structureChildren[] children { get; set; }


}
class structureChildren
{
    public structureChildren[] children { get; set; }
    public string myentity { get; set; }
    public bool sonGuide { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public Int64 structureId { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}

static readonly string myjson = @"[
  {
    ""children"": [
      {
        ""children"": [
          {
            ""children"": [
              {
                ""children"": [],
                ""myentity"": ""ENT3_A"",
                ""from"": ""2019-10-01"",
                ""structureId"": 34353,
                ""to"": null
              },
              {
                ""children"": [
                  {
                    ""children"": [],
                    ""myentity"": ""ENT3_B"",
                    ""from"": ""2019-10-01"",
                    ""structureId"": 34349,
                    ""to"": null
                  },
                  {
                    ""children"": [],
                    ""myentity"": ""ENT3_C"",
                    ""from"": ""2019-10-01"",
                    ""structureId"": 34351,
                    ""to"": null
                  }
                ],
                ""myentity"": ""ENT2_A"",
                ""from"": ""2019-10-01"",
                ""structureId"": 34348,
                ""to"": null
              }
            ],
            ""myentity"": ""ENT1_1"",
            ""from"": ""2019-10-01"",
            ""structureId"": 34348,
            ""to"": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]";
```

Output:

```
, 0
ENT1_1, 1
ENT3_A, 2
ENT2_A, 2
ENT3_B, 3
ENT3_C, 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in two ways, with a stack/queue or recursion. I personally prefer stacks since recursion is hard(er) to debug. This is a quick draft. I'm sure someone else can give you a fancy recursion version with Linq, but I think this illustrates the steps you need to take better.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{       
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var structure = new StructureTree();
        var currentStack = new Stack<StructureChildren>(structure.children);
        var nextStack = new Stack<StructureChildren>();
        var flatStructure = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        int currentLevel = 0;
        bool loop = true;
        
        while (loop)
        {
            var currentItem = currentStack.Pop();
            
            foreach (var child in currentItem.children)
                nextStack.Push(child);
            
            flatStructure.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(currentLevel, currentItem.myentity));
            
            if (currentStack.Count == 0)
            {
                if (nextStack.Count == 0)
                    break;

                currentLevel++;
                currentStack = new Stack<StructureChildren>(nextStack);
                nextStack.Clear();
            }
        }       
    }
    
    public class StructureTree
    {
        public StructureChildren[] children { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class StructureChildren
    {
        public StructureChildren[] children { get; set; }
        public string myentity { get; set; }
        public bool sonGuide { get; set; }
        public string from { get; set; }
        public Int64 structureId { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PS: Please look into the naming convention provided by Microsoft. `Class` names should be CapitalizedAtEveryWord and property names too. Your current naming scheme is typically used for Java, not C#.